# Populate a second entity after a form submit in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I'm recently new Symfony (2.8) and I'm trying, that after an image file submission from a form, is to populate a second entity with the mains colors of the image.

For now, I just made a test from the controller like this:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($image);

        $extractor->setImage($image->getFile());
        $palette = $extractor->extractPalette();

        foreach($palette as $color => $weight){
            $imageColor = new Color();
            $imageColor->setImage($image);
            $imageColor->setRgb($color);
            $imageColor->setWeight($weight);

            $em->persist($imageColor);

        }

        $em->flush();
```

It's working but I don't think that the colors should be in the form or the controller neither is the image entity.
So, how should I deal with the colors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions in mind to save `Colors` outside your controller:

1. Create a Doctrine listener (on prePersist and preUpdate) that will generate `Colors` when an `Image` is persisted.
2. Before `flush`, dispatch a custom Event and catch it with an EventListener. When caught, execute method that populate `Colors`.

**Advantage of solution 1:** `Colors` will automatically be generated for an `Image`, whether you are in a Controller, a Command, or somewhere else.

**Advantage of solution 2:** You can decide more precisely when you want to generate Colors, by dispatching your custom event.

Comment: Thank you @Terenoth. - Sorry for the late reply.